# No file or variants found for asset: Images/xyz.jpg

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, pubspec

I am getting an error that flutter is unable to load my image which is stored in the Images directory.

I checked the indentation for the pubspec.yaml file,

and also checked the similar question for the solution to the error but nothing seems to work.

below are images for the pubspec.yaml file and code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('Images/xyz.jpg'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

if you could please let me know what am I doing wrong here, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Image file Extensions  is jpeg but use jpg is error change name in pubspec.yaml and widget to  jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pubspecc.yaml file like below hope it help:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - Images/
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Ameer Amjed the problem was not with the indentations or the code , it was the extension used for the image. the correct extension is important here, it was .jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

if your yaml file is in the root of the project, you must include the lib directory in the path of the yaml file

assets:

- lib/Images/xyz.jepg

in you class

placeholder: AssetImage('lib/Images/xyz.jepg'),